# Open source self-hosted alternative to Sendy

Tags: open-source, email, self-hosted, newsletter

I use [Sendy](http://sendy.co/) to manage and send newsletters and marketing emails.

I was trying to find an open source alternative that uses Amazon SES or Mailgun as backend.

Comment: Please describe the features that you expect. Most of us don't know Sendy. Thanks!

Comment: What prevents you from adding Mailgun SMTP credentials into your usual email client (or [these](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-mostly-free-mass-mailing-applications/)) and send from there? If your bulk is not big it is quite viable solution

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [NodeMailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/), a tool to easily send (bulk) e-mails via SMTP, SMTP server pools, GMail, Mailgun, SendGrid, etc. using node.js as scripting engine (i.e. it's written in JavaScript).

See especially their [notes about delivering bulk e-mails](http://www.nodemailer.com/#delivering-bulk-mail).

[The source code is on GitHub](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) and it's [licensed under the MIT License](http://www.nodemailer.com/#license).

Answer (score 2):

[Hectane](https://github.com/hectane/hectane)<sup>*</sup> is a fairly capable open-source (MIT license) SMTP client that can directly send emails via SMTP. Unlike a number of popular MTAs, Hectane receives emails via a simple HTTP API instead of SMTP.

For example, assuming you have the application configured to listen on port `8025` (the default), instructing it to send an email with cURL would be as simple as:

```
curl \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"from":"me@example.com","to":["you@example.com"],"subject":"Test","text":"Body of the message."}'
    http://127.0.0.1:8025/v1/send
```

More information:

- Application consists of a single executable
- No dependencies on any shared libraries
- Uses an outgoing mail queue with persistent disk storage

There are a number of different ways to run the application:

- Grab a `.tar.gz` with the latest binary from [here](https://github.com/hectane/hectane/releases)
- Install on Ubuntu from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hectane/+archive/ubuntu/hectane)
- Deploy using [this Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/hectane/hectane/)
- Deploy using [this Juju charm](https://jujucharms.com/hectane/precise/1)

<sub>* I am the author of the application</sub>

Comment: As I got it, there is no RPA package of Hectane, so it is impossible to use it on RHEL/CentOS?